# React input field doesn't see value changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datepicker

When i picking `date`, `event` doesn't see anything, nothing happened, i cannot extract my `value` from input field. What **** ? Is it problem React or Datepicker? In datepicker manual nothing say about that, http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index.html

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dueDate: 'Date and time'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.initDatepicker();
  }
  
  initDatepicker(){
    $(this.refs.datepicker).datepicker();
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Choose date!</h3>
        <input
          value={this.state.dueDate}
          type='text'
          onChange={event => console.log(event)}
          ref='datepicker'
        />
      </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use material-ui for React. It works perfectly.

Comment: thanks, why never heard about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bound the input field value to the state property `dueDate`. Now if you want to modify it, you have to refresh the state property on input field change, therefore:

```
onChange={event => this.setState({dueDate: event.target.value})}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a controlled component. You set a state value to input element. If the state changes, your input value change. So you change the code below like,

```
  // input element
    <input value={this.state.dueDate} onChange={this.handleDueDate}/>

    // handleDueDate method
    handleDueDate(event){
        this.setState({
            dueDate: event.target.value
        })
    }
```

If you change your code looks like, its works fine.